# Managing extensions to built-in objects

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am working on a project where code-size is of paramount importance and compiling my code using Google Closure Compiler's ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS. I need to extend certain built-in objects (such as Date and Number), using their prototype. I wanted to package these extensions into a reusable library and have the compiler only include those that are actually used in the code.

The only way I have come up with so far is to wrap each one in a '@defined' constant which I can individually toggle as a compiler flag. Every other way seems to either include all or none of these extensions. This is rather unwieldy, is there a better way?

To Clarify:

**In Library File**

```
Number.prototype.foo = function() { ... }

Number.prototype.bar = function() { ... }

Number.prototype.something = function() { ... }
```

**In Code**

```
function somefunc() {
   25.foo();
   ...
   41.foo();
}
```

What I don't want is Number.bar and Number.something appearing in the compiled code, as the are not used in the primary source.

Comment: If you add these on the protoype and include it in the normal compilation, you wouldn't need any special handling for them.  Using the compiler's module support would let you keep them as a separate library. What am I missing?

Comment: @John What I need is the ability to selectively include these extensions in the compiled code, based on whether they are actually used. For instance, if I have 3 prototype methods that extend Number, but I only use one of them, I only want that one the be included in the code, i.e. removing dead/unused code.

Comment: @grim What you describe should happen automatically. Testing at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/ this code compiles to zero bytes: `Date.prototype.foo = function() { alert('foo'); };` proving that since it isn't used it is being removed. Can you give us a specific example (including compiler parameters) where it fails to be removed?